# JAXB Update List of strings

Tags: java, string, reference, jaxb

I have to work with a JAXB type (named "runtime") that contains the following XSD element:

```xml
<xsd:element name="scripts" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:list itemType="xsd:string" />
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Thus I have code like:

```
runtime.getScripts()
```

Is there as way I can update the script value? The following does not work:

```
for (String aScript : runtime.getScripts()) {
final String updatedScript = "dummy";
                aScript = updatedScript; // ?
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `set` method on `List` to update the values:

**Demo**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> scripts = new ArrayList<String>();
        scripts.add("foo");
        scripts.add("bar");

        for(int x=0,size=scripts.size(); x<size; x++) {
            scripts.set(x, "dummy");
        }

        for(String script : scripts) {
            System.out.println(script);
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
dummy
dummy
```